# how do i get facebook photo of public user in php

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrive images of facebook public profiles by searching an email.
My company has a CRM of about 5 million clients in our system.
I want to use the facebook Graph API but without asking the users to login to facebook.
is it possible to login back end with one user email and password to facebook api and search for public profiles?

by the way i used this example that makes a simple search but it retrived a captcha after i searched a lot of users

example: https://github.com/shlomnissan/profilepicgrabber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t search for users by email, and you shouldn´t be able to. Without authorizing the user, there is nothing you can do - which is a good thing, because without asking a user you should not be able to connect his email with his Facebook profile pic.

Maybe it was possible to use the [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search) with emails, but it should not be possible anymore. In any case, you will hit the API limit very fast.

Btw, scraping is not allowed, and captchas are usually there to prevent people from scraping: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I wanted to login to facebook with the API and use my email and password and then use Search API, and this way i don't need an authontification from the user because it's my details. Is that possible?

About Search API how do i know what is the limit of number of searches for each day/connection? and why did you say it should not be possible anymore? is it going to be removed? Thanks alot

Comment: i think you don´t need to authorize any use to use the search api, but you don´t get anything else than then app scoped id of the user - and for his details you MUST authorize that specific user, you can´t grab the details with anyone elses login.

Comment: about limits: there are no specific ones, you will know when you hit the limit when you get an error back instead of a result. in general, they say "600 calls in 600 seconds" afaik.

Comment: about email search: it´s not in the docs (at least not anymore), so yeah, it will definitely be removed. people should connect their facebook accounts only if they want to, you can´t just connect their profile pic from facebook to their email without their permission.

Comment: thank you you helped alot. about the documentation of searching by mail (in case of user logged in) here is the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2 it's under category os Searching

Comment: that link is in my answer, they don´t mention mail search anywhere in it.